# What is the proper way to navigate between windows?

Tags: java, user-interface, coding-style

I am trying to make a simple Customer tracking program.It stars with a window with 4 buttons and you choose a task to do.

I need to navigate between different windows 
-Home Menu
-New Customer
-Customer
-Reports

What i do is creating different Jframes for each task but i don't know if it is the right way to do.

So my question is What is the proper way to navigate between windows on Java?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Please* do not create multiple JFrames unless absolutely necessary.

**Why?**

- There's multiple icons in the taskbar (on Windows and Linux).
- Switching windows is an added burden to the user.
- It raises issues with, e.g., the close button (do they all close if any close? is there one master?), etc.

**Instead:**

Consider [using a `JTabbedPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html).

> To create a tabbed pane, instantiate `JTabbedPane`, create the components you wish it to display, and then add the components to the tabbed pane using the `addTab` method.

For example:

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

JComponent someComponent = ...
tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 1", someComponent);

JComponent anotherComponent = ...
tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 2", anotherComponent);
```

---

Alternatively, you could [use a `CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) if you only want your users to see one view at a time.

> The `CardLayout` class manages two or more components (usually `JPanel` instances) that share the same display space. Conceptually, each component that a `CardLayout` manages is like a playing card or trading card in a stack, where only the top card is visible at any time.

Comment: Jtabbed does not seem to be right choice.Actually what i want is something like in android UI.You start the app,tab on something a new interface appears.

Comment: +1 for `JFrame` pointers and yeah `CardLayout` is a better option